# Why whenever I'm sending a mock GPS signal the emulator crashes?

Tags: android, android-layout

Just like the title - whenever I'm trying to send a mock signal with DDMS in Eclipse it's crashing. Can someone provide me some guidance on that? Here's what I'm getting from the LogCat console:

```
    06-06 17:47:25.986: DEBUG/dalvikvm(123): GC_EXPLICIT freed 155K, 52% free 2716K/5639K, external 2110K/2137K, paused 71ms
06-06 17:47:27.366: INFO/DEBUG(30): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-06 17:47:27.366: INFO/DEBUG(30): Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic:2.3.1/GSI11/93351:eng/test-keys'
06-06 17:47:27.366: INFO/DEBUG(30): pid: 60, tid: 138  >>> system_server <<<
06-06 17:47:27.366: INFO/DEBUG(30): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
06-06 17:47:27.376: INFO/DEBUG(30):  r0 00000000  r1 406bf150  r2 41adfab4  r3 4643dc74
06-06 17:47:27.376: INFO/DEBUG(30):  r4 00000130  r5 00000000  r6 406bf150  r7 41adfab4
06-06 17:47:27.376: INFO/DEBUG(30):  r8 84301321  r9 84302240  10 00100000  fp 00000001
06-06 17:47:27.376: INFO/DEBUG(30):  ip 82f0e7d4  sp 4643dc60  lr 82f0ab37  pc 82f07d0e  cpsr 00000030
06-06 17:47:27.666: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #00  pc 00007d0e  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
06-06 17:47:27.666: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #01  pc 0000ab32  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
06-06 17:47:27.666: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #02  pc 000012ca  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
06-06 17:47:27.676: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #03  pc 000014ae  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
06-06 17:47:27.676: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #04  pc 00011a7c  /system/lib/libc.so
06-06 17:47:27.686: INFO/DEBUG(30):          #05  pc 00011640  /system/lib/libc.so
06-06 17:47:27.686: INFO/DEBUG(30): code around pc:
06-06 17:47:27.686: INFO/DEBUG(30): 82f07cec ab04b082 9301cb04 6f646804 b00247a0 
06-06 17:47:27.686: INFO/DEBUG(30): 82f07cfc bc08bc10 4718b002 b510b40c ab04b082 
06-06 17:47:27.686: INFO/DEBUG(30): 82f07d0c 6804cb04 34f89301 47a06824 bc10b002 
06-06 17:47:27.686: INFO/DEBUG(30): 82f07d1c b002bc08 46c04718 b510b40c ab04b082 
06-06 17:47:27.686: INFO/DEBUG(30): 82f07d2c 9301cb04 34986804 47a06824 bc10b002 
06-06 17:47:27.696: INFO/DEBUG(30): code around lr:
06-06 17:47:27.696: INFO/DEBUG(30): 82f0ab14 91099008 f7fb6aa0 900aeb14 1c3a910b 
06-06 17:47:27.696: INFO/DEBUG(30): 82f0ab24 6b646b23 930c1c28 1c31940d f7fd9b0f 
06-06 17:47:27.696: INFO/DEBUG(30): 82f0ab34 4906f8e7 44791c28 f7ff3150 b011fe1d 
06-06 17:47:27.696: INFO/DEBUG(30): 82f0ab44 46c0bdf0 0000454c 000042c8 00000786 
06-06 17:47:27.696: INFO/DEBUG(30): 82f0ab54 f7fbb510 bd10ec7c 4802b510 f7fb4478 
06-06 17:47:27.696: INFO/DEBUG(30): stack:
06-06 17:47:27.696: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc20  d97f62b7  
06-06 17:47:27.696: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc24  40c7d685  
06-06 17:47:27.696: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc28  0000000a  
06-06 17:47:27.706: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc2c  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.706: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc30  0000ab90  [heap]
06-06 17:47:27.706: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc34  81d48bd3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-06 17:47:27.706: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc38  0000ab90  [heap]
06-06 17:47:27.706: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc3c  4643dc6c  
06-06 17:47:27.706: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc40  00010004  [heap]
06-06 17:47:27.706: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc44  81d3761b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-06 17:47:27.706: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc48  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.706: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc4c  afd0dcc4  /system/lib/libc.so
06-06 17:47:27.716: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc50  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.716: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc54  4643de00  
06-06 17:47:27.716: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc58  df002777  
06-06 17:47:27.716: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc5c  e3a070ad  
06-06 17:47:27.716: INFO/DEBUG(30): #00 4643dc60  00000001  
06-06 17:47:27.716: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc64  8053bf25  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
06-06 17:47:27.716: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc68  00000130  
06-06 17:47:27.716: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc6c  82f0ab37  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
06-06 17:47:27.716: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc70  41adfab4  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
06-06 17:47:27.716: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc74  00000003  
06-06 17:47:27.726: INFO/DEBUG(30): #01 4643dc78  4284dfce  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
06-06 17:47:27.726: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc7c  4042b604  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-06 17:47:27.726: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc80  cffeb075  
06-06 17:47:27.726: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc84  c05e8561  
06-06 17:47:27.726: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc88  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.726: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc8c  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.726: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc90  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.726: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc94  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.726: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc98  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.736: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dc9c  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.736: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dca0  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.736: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dca4  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.736: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dca8  61d1d700  
06-06 17:47:27.736: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dcac  00000130  
06-06 17:47:27.736: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dcb0  4643de56  
06-06 17:47:27.736: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dcb4  00000003  
06-06 17:47:27.736: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dcb8  0000000a  
06-06 17:47:27.736: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dcbc  4643dde8  
06-06 17:47:27.736: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dcc0  00000000  
06-06 17:47:27.747: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dcc4  4643de6c  
06-06 17:47:27.747: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dcc8  00000001  
06-06 17:47:27.747: INFO/DEBUG(30):     4643dccc  843012cd  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
06-06 17:47:31.136: DEBUG/skia(122): purging 6K from font cache [1 entries]
06-06 17:47:31.347: DEBUG/dalvikvm(122): GC_EXPLICIT freed 207K, 50% free 2920K/5767K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 205ms
06-06 17:47:36.146: DEBUG/skia(376): purging 340K from font cache [44 entries]
06-06 17:47:36.276: DEBUG/dalvikvm(376): GC_EXPLICIT freed 598K, 52% free 3354K/6855K, external 2859K/3559K, paused 130ms
06-06 17:47:41.156: DEBUG/skia(60): purging 135K from font cache [14 entries]
06-06 17:47:41.336: DEBUG/dalvikvm(60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 146K, 49% free 4533K/8775K, external 4373K/5573K, paused 182ms
06-06 17:47:42.577: DEBUG/Zygote(32): Process 60 terminated by signal (11)
06-06 17:47:42.577: INFO/Zygote(32): Exit zygote because system server (60) has terminated
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'SurfaceFlinger' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'sensorservice' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'entropy' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'power' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'batteryinfo' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'telephony.registry' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'usagestats' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'account' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'package' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'activity' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'meminfo' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'cpuinfo' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'permission' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'content' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'hardware' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'battery' died
06-06 17:47:42.676: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'vibrator' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'alarm' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'window' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'device_policy' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'statusbar' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'clipboard' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'network_management' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'input_method' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'netstat' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'wifi' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'connectivity' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'throttle' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'accessibility' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'mount' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'notification' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'devicestoragemonitor' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'location' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'search' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'dropbox' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'wallpaper' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'audio' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'uimode' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'backup' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'appwidget' died
06-06 17:47:42.697: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'diskstats' died
06-06 17:47:42.716: ERROR/installd(34): eof
06-06 17:47:42.716: ERROR/installd(34): failed to read size
06-06 17:47:42.716: INFO/installd(34): closing connection
06-06 17:47:42.716: DEBUG/qemud(37): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 11
06-06 17:47:42.786: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
06-06 17:47:42.786: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.audio_policy' died
06-06 17:47:42.786: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.player' died
06-06 17:47:42.786: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.camera' died
06-06 17:47:42.816: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'isms' died
06-06 17:47:42.816: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'simphonebook' died
06-06 17:47:42.816: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'iphonesubinfo' died
06-06 17:47:42.816: INFO/ServiceManager(27): service 'phone' died
06-06 17:47:42.946: INFO/Netd(449): Netd 1.0 starting
06-06 17:47:44.016: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(450): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
06-06 17:47:44.026: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(450): CheckJNI is ON
06-06 17:47:44.497: INFO/(448): ServiceManager: 0xad50
06-06 17:47:44.497: DEBUG/AudioHardwareInterface(448): setMode(NORMAL)
06-06 17:47:44.517: INFO/CameraService(448): CameraService started (pid=448)
06-06 17:47:44.547: INFO/AudioFlinger(448): AudioFlinger's thread 0xc650 ready to run
06-06 17:47:45.326: INFO/SamplingProfilerIntegration(450): Profiler is disabled.
06-06 17:47:45.407: INFO/Zygote(450): Preloading classes...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you do to trigger that?

Comment: I'm going to DDMS tab in Eclipse. Then When you scroll down to "Location Controls" and "Manual" you have 2 textboxes for long and lat. I'm entering them and click send. That's it...

Answer (score 2):

Its a Bug in the 2.3 Emulator: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13015